# Merge the result of an Inner Join to a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Using SQL query I have a successfully result used an inner join, but the results are displayed underneath the query.

How can I jot the results down in an already existing table ie merge with it?

```
UPDATE CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData
SET PressNumber = master.dbo.TagTable
WHERE CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData.TagIndex = master.dbo.TagTable.TagIndex;
```

When I execute this I get an error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   The multi-part identifier "master.dbo.TagTable.TagIndex" could not be bound.

Dont know where am I going wrong. Both the tables exist by the way.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The description of the problem does not do a good job conveying your question.

Comment: I have a few columns in each table, one of them is the TagIndex which is the same in both of the tables. The other is PressNumber in one table and TagName in the other, both of them represent the same thing and I want to pass the value of TagName to PressNumber matching the TagIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.PressNumber = t2.pressnumber 
from CuringHistoryData.dbo.CuringData as t1 inner join  master.dbo.TagTable as t2 on
t1.TagIndex = t2.TagIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks Madhivanan but I still get an error with this code,
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 't1'.

Comment: I was about to answer that.. Used ON and it worked. Thanks a ton